# Invisible mouse in Virtual Box, Ubuntu 14

Tags: mouse

I'm using Oracle Virtualbox 5.1.22 with Ubuntu 14.04.5.  All was well until I installed the Virtualbox extension pack (not the guest package).  I installed the correct pack for the Virtualbox I'm running (5.1.22 r115126).  Now when I open Virtualbox, everything is fine.  When I power on Ubuntu, I lose the mouse immediately.  It's totally invisible but it's there because when I physically move my mouse around I can see things being affected, but it's invisible inside and outside Ubuntu.  I have no option but to press the power button on my desktop computer to shut down.  Dead in the water.